# How to change the language of the menu on GUI version

Tags: gui-emacs

how to change language of the menu? I go to Options > multilingual envi... > set language ...; but nothing happends.

[image]

Comment: Down-voted just so that "Community" will not [auto-bump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362269/324105) this question again (which was posted by a non-user, who is consequently unlikely to be contributing to this any further).

Answer (score 2):

> I go to Options > multilingual envi... > set language ...

It makes sense to some extent.  It will make Emacs use the language you set up whenever possible.

For example, if you set your `language-environment` to `"Hebrew"`, then Emacs will show you *TUTORIAL.he* instead of *TUTORIAL* (after you type `C-h t`).

But this is just “*whenever possible*”.  Since Emacs doesn't have a translation for GUI text, you won't get what you want.

Note that GNU Emacs is **free/libre** software, so if you need the translation, you can edit its source code and build an Emacs which fits your needs perfectly!

(Though that's really complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

If I've guessed correctly, you're hoping that Emacs' own user interface is translated into different languages, which is unfortunately not the case (or at least not to my knowledge).

The menu option you selected calls `set-language-environment` which has the following purpose:

> Set up multilingual environment for using LANGUAGE-NAME.
>   This sets the coding system priority and the default input method
>   and sometimes other things.  LANGUAGE-NAME should be a string
>   which is the name of a language environment.  For example, "Latin-1"
>   specifies the character set for the major languages of Western Europe.

For more information, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Language Environments` <kbd>RET</kbd> specifically, and its parent node `(emacs)International` regarding support for international character sets in general.

Comment: Thanks for clarify the purpose of the option `set-language-environment`. It's a pity that emacs don't has a gui translate.